# Can I prevent having to pass the same resource argument to instances of different classes

Tags: python, pyspark

I am wondering whether there is a better way to achieve what I want. I have a Python program in which I use classes to organize code. However, all these classes require an opened resource to be passed to them in order to work.

In my particular case, I am defining classes that perform distinct transformations on a dataframe that is read using a spark session resource, as shown with the snippets below.

I am wondering whether there is a better design pattern which would *not* require me to pass the same argument (in my example a spark session object `spark`) to each class member. Note that sometimes I am initiating class instances inside other classes, which shows why I need to pass the same resource, rather than creating and destroying it on the fly.

In other words: is there a way to *share* the resource across instances of classes without needing to pass it explicitly?

```py
# main.py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from etl import Source, OtherSource, JoinedSources

# Retrieve the resource
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

joined_sources = JoinedSources(spark=spark)
joined_sources_processed = joined_source.etl()

...

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()
```

```py
# etl.py

class Source:
    """Class to organize ETL specific for `Source` dataframe"""
    def __init__(self, spark):
        """Ïnitialize object, passing it the spark resource"""
        self.spark = spark

    def etl(self):
        """Return a transformed object (in this case, just the dataframe read from a table"""
        return self.spark.read.table('db.source_table')

class OtherSource:
    """Class to organize ETL specific for `OtherSource` dataframe"""
    def __init__(self, spark):
        """Ïnitialize object, passing it the spark resource"""
        self.spark = spark

    def etl(self):
        """Return a transformed object (in this case, the DataFrame with dropped duplicates"""
        return self.spark.read.table('db.other_source_table').drop_duplicates()

class JoinedSources:
    """Class to organize ETL for `JoinedSources` dataframe, which instantiates `Source` and `OtherSource` objects"""
    def __init__(self, spark):
        """Ïnitialize object, passing it the spark resource"""
        self.spark = spark

    def etl(self):
        """Return a dataframe that joins the processed `Source` and `OtherSource` objects"""

        source_processed = Source(spark=self.spark).etl()
        other_source_processed = OtherSource(spark=self.spark).etl()

        return soure_processed.join(other_source_processed, on='key')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you would add one more class that manages all others?

First you would need modify your a code a bit, like this:

```
# etl.py
from abc import ABC, abstractstaticmethod

class EtlInterface(ABC):
    
    @abstractstaticmethod
    def etl(spark):
        raise NotImplementedError
    
        
class Source(EtlInterface):
    """Class to organize ETL specific for `Source` dataframe"""
    
    @staticmethod
    def etl(spark):
        """Return a transformed object (in this case, just the dataframe read from a table"""
        return spark.read.table('db.source_table')

class OtherSource(EtlInterface):
    """Class to organize ETL specific for `OtherSource` dataframe"""
    
    @staticmethod
    def etl(self, spark):
        """Return a transformed object (in this case, the DataFrame with dropped duplicates"""
        return spark.read.table('db.other_source_table').drop_duplicates()

class JoinedSources(EtlInterface):
    """Class to organize ETL for `JoinedSources` dataframe, which instantiates `Source` and `OtherSource` objects"""
    
    @staticmethod
    def etl(spark):
        """Return a dataframe that joins the processed `Source` and `OtherSource` objects"""

        source_processed = Source.etl(spark)
        other_source_processed = OtherSource.etl(spark)

        return soure_processed.join(other_source_processed, on='key')
```

Next add class that will take as argument class object and run method that will always trigger **etl** method:

```
class EtlManager:
    def __init__(self, spark, executor):
        self.spark = spark
        self.executor = executor
    
    def run(self):
        return self.executor.etl(self.spark)
```

So if you want to run **JoinedSources** class:

```
manager = EtlManager(spark, JoinedSources)
output = manager.run()
```

**run** method will trigger **etl** method of class that will be passed as **executor** argument.

Finally still all classes will require **spark** variable, but that will be passed only once into **Etlmanager** class that will handle it.

Comment: That's a nice solution. I will try this approach and see whether I don't have any weird edge case in my code that would prevent me from using this. If it works I'll accept your answer!